# Delete all items from TreeView that don't have descendant at specified level

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have one TreeView (TreeNode) and I need to delete all nodes that don't have descendant at level 4 (root level = 0).

My TreeView don't have any node with level bigger than 4.

I try this:

```
private void RemoveEmptyNodes(TreeNode node)
{
   if (node.Children.Count > 0)
   {
      List<TreeNode> aux = new List<TreeNode>(node.Children);
      foreach (TreeNode childNode in aux)
      {
         RemoveEmptyNodes(childNode);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      node.Parent.DeleteChild(node);
   }
}
```

But this only delete nodes at level 3 and I need to delete in all levels

Comment: Can't see why it wont delete on every lvl, try debug? and how about .remove instead of RemoveEmptyNodes?

Comment: Which `TreeView` are you using?

Comment: I'm using a lib named [TreeViewLib](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView).